# MATLAB: How to efficiently create a matrix, which is the result of an outer product?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

I have two vectors a and b and some function f. 
What is the best way (in performance) to define a matrix in MATLAB of such a kind:

```
A(m,n) = f(a(m)*b(n)) / ( (f(a(m)) * f(b(n)) )
```

Is it possible not to use nested loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at a computer right now, but try

```
A=f(a*b')./(f(a)*f(b)')
```

where a and b are column vectors. a*b' is outer product.

Comment: That depends on whether a,b are row vectors or column vectors. You can make it more robust by doing a = a(:), b= b(:) first.

Answer (score 3):

If `f` supports vector syntax, than it is just:

```
   [A,B] = meshgrid(a,b);
   M = f(A.*B) ./ ( f(A).*f(B) );
```

---

By the way, I am not sure that the performance will be better than regular loop. Better profile and check. Since the introduction of JIT, Matlab loops often run faster than vectorized operations.

---

Here is an example:

```
function CalcGrid()
    a = 1:10;
    b = 1:10;

    [A,B] = meshgrid(a,b);
    M = f(A.*B) ./ ( f(A).*f(B) );
    figure;surf(M);
end

function y = f(x)
    y = x-1;
end
```

Comment: Cool. i've totally forgotten about meshgrid!

Comment: @jacksonslsmg4 this implementation evaluates f too many times. You don't want to pass matrices to f since most of the entries are repeated..

Comment: I prefer to use `ndgrid` in calculations, since the first output increments along the first dimension, and the second output increments along the second dimension.